# Can cursor be use in UPDATE and DELETE in Function

Tags: oracle, function, plsql

I have one doupt while I try to use `UPDATE` and `DELETE` method.
So starting from basic function something like

```
FUNCTION GET_ANSWER(p_questionId IN INT)
    RETURN SYS_REFCURSOR IS 
    rc  SYS_REFCURSOR;
    /*getAnswer*/
BEGIN
  OPEN rc FOR
    SELECT * FROM answers WHERE AnswerID = p_questionId;
  RETURN rc;
END GET_ANSWER;
```

While I try to use DELETE or UPDATE method I get error message

```
Error(3529,1): PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "DELETE" when expecting one of the following:     ( - + case mod new not null select with <an identifier>    <a double-quoted delimited-identifier> <a bind variable>    continue avg count current exists max min prior sql stddev    sum variance execute forall merge time timestamp interval    date <a string literal with character set specification>    <a number> <a single-quoted SQL string> pipe    <an alternatively-quoted string literal with character set specification> 


Error(3530,1): PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "RETURN"  

Error(3536,1): PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "END" 




FUNCTION DELETE_ACTIVITY(p_activityId IN INT) 
RETURN SYS_REFCURSOR IS 
rc  SYS_REFCURSOR;
BEGIN
OPEN rc FOR
DELETE FROM activities WHERE id = p_activityId;
RETURN rc;
END DELETE_ACTIVITY;
```

What is wrong here ? Wher did I made mistake ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't do it via cursor, but simply

```
DELETE FROM answers WHERE AnswerID = p_questionId;
```

Also, make it a **procedure**, not a function.

---

As of `UPDATE`, well - it depends on what you want to update and how, but - generally:

```
update answers set
  some_column = some_value
where ansewrID = p_questionId
```

---

Why a procedure and not a function:

```
SQL> create or replace function f_test return number is
  2  begin
  3    delete from test;
  4    return 1;
  5  end;
  6  /

Function created.

SQL> select f_test from dual;
select f_test from dual
       *
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-14551: cannot perform a DML operation inside a query
ORA-06512: at "SCOTT.F_TEST", line 3


SQL>
```

**However**, if a function is an autonomous transaction, you *can* do that, but - not recommended:

```
SQL> create or replace function f_test return number is
  2    pragma autonomous_transaction;
  3  begin
  4    delete from test;
  5    commit;
  6    return 1;
  7  end;
  8  /

Function created.

SQL> select f_test from dual;

    F_TEST
----------
         1

SQL>
```

Comment: Thank you for answer. I get the point right now :) 
One more question, why you recommend to use procedure not a function ?

Comment: You're welcome. Because you can't delete within a function :) See a demonstration at the bottom of the answer.

Comment: No problem, I'm glad if it helped.

Answer (score 0):

Cursors are only used for SELECT statements.  You cannot open a cursor for an INSERT, UPDATE or DELETE statement.

See [the documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/20/lnpls/static-sql.html#GUID-05C186C1-147E-4DA6-8133-F42B24C73ADA)

> An explicit cursor definition has this syntax:
>
> CURSOR cursor_name [ parameter_list ] [ RETURN return_type ]   IS
> select_statement;